# Punctuation for title and caption

Tags: punctuation, titles

I'm displaying a title and caption along with an artist's painting. Are the quote marks correct like this?

> Title: “The Tree”
>
> Caption: “A black tree in the wild”

Comment: If you are displaying this in a gallery, ask the gallery's preference. If that doesn't lead anywhere, ask the artist. If the artist is unavailable, I'd go with drm's suggestion.

Comment: The caption might be improved, too.  What is the painting an image of?  Just a black tree?  Any surroundings?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need quotes in the title or the caption:

> Title: The Tree
>
> Caption: A black tree in the wild